# Chart.js Doughnut Chart Sharing filters with Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am trying to have the Doughnut chart filters affecting the bar chart values, imagine, I have the same values in the bar chart as I have for the Doughnut  Chart and when I click to disable a value in the pie chart I want it to disable the same value in the bar chart.

This is my code to the Doughnut Chart:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("pieChartt"), {
                    type: 'doughnut',
                    data: {
                        labels: ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
                        datasets: [
                          {
                              label: "Example",
                              backgroundColor: ["#F2C15A", "#F58557", "#F55B51", "#286278", "#004250", "#3D6272", "#ACD7DD"],
                              data: [300, 200, 600, 100, 478, 145, 354, 123]
                          }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        tooltips: {
                            callbacks: {
                                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                    var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
                                    var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                                    var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
                                    var total = 0;
                                    for (var i in allData) {
                                        total += allData[i];
                                    }
                                    var tooltipPercentage = Math.round((tooltipData / total) * 100);
                                    return tooltipLabel + ': ' + tooltipData + ' (' + tooltipPercentage + '%)';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This is the code for my Bar Chart:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: areaChartData,
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                            position: 'bottom',
                            labels: {
                                fontColor: "#000080",
                            }
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            mode: 'index'
                        },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                },
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: "Test Label",
                                    fontColor: "black"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So, what I want is, When I click in the Label of `"Test 1"`in doughnut chart it affects the same value in the bar chart.
Is it possible ?